android get current display fragment
I want to get current display fragment in MainActivity.
And I use this code:
val currentFragment = supportFragmentManager.fragments.last()

My question is: when I extend Fragment, I write new member which not in Fragment, like:
class GalleryFragment : Fragment() {
  val GalleryFragment_specific_member: Int=0
}

now how can I get GalleryFragment_specific_member use currentFragment 

class GalleryFragment : Fragment() {
    val galleryFragment_specific_member: Int = 0
}

val currentFragment = supportFragmentManager.fragments.lastOrNull()
if (currentFragment is GalleryFragment) {
    val specificMember = currentFragment.galleryFragment_specific_member
    println("GalleryFragment_specific_member value is: $specificMember")
} else {
    println("The current fragment is not a GalleryFragment")
}

=================
sample
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager

class GalleryFragment : Fragment() {
    val galleryFragmentSpecificMember: Int = 42
}

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Add GalleryFragment to the fragment manager (for demonstration purposes)
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, GalleryFragment())
            .commit()

        // Access the current fragment and its specific member after a delay (for demonstration purposes)
        // In a real app, you might want to ensure the fragment transaction is complete before accessing
        supportFragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener {
            val currentFragment = supportFragmentManager.fragments.lastOrNull()
            if (currentFragment is GalleryFragment) {
                val specificMember = currentFragment.galleryFragmentSpecificMember
                println("GalleryFragment_specific_member value is: $specificMember")
            } else {
                println("The current fragment is not a GalleryFragment")
            }
        }
    }
}


I still suffer from Unresolved reference: galleryFragmentSpecificMember when build.

It's me again.
I finally find the code:
val currentFragment = supportFragmentManager.fragments.last()

is NOT what I want. But below is:
val currentFragment=supportFragmentManager.fragments.last()?.getChildFragmentManager()?.fragments?.get(0)

this code work very fine with if (currentFragment is GalleryFragment) {
And I totally donnot know why the below one work, and the upper one not work. But the total building is built by someone else, right? When you step to this building, it's the time you need to follow its clownish constructers.
